# placing a button on each row (in a cell) in Google Sheet that, when pressed, gets system time and places in adjacent cell in that row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was directed here by GAFE engineers as scripting wasn't directly supported by Google. I've started looking at the script editor and thought I need some direction to get where I want to be.

I would like to have a time dropoff, adjustment, time pickup, & total time cells in each row where there is a button next to the total time cell where when clicked would get the system time and place it in that row's time dropoff cell. Then it will calculate total time as `((time pickup - time drop off) - adjustment)`.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: There is no "built-in" way to put a button in a cell.  It is possible to create an image, and assign a script to it.  But trying to insert an image into cells in multiple rows probably won't work.  You can add an On Edit event trigger that monitors the spreadsheet for edits, and then runs when an edit is done.  You could type an "x" into the cell instead of having a button, and then have code run if it detects that there is an "x" in the cell.  From the Apps Script code editor, click "help" and then "documentation", the search on "trigger".

Comment: Thank you. If image can't be input then I like your "X" idea as trigger. I will look up the "trigger" idea and see where I can get to ... thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying as in I use the onEdit simple trigger but I'm a little confused as in how the script editor associates with a particular cell in the sheet ... what are some key words I should be searching for to understand this relationship between a 'cell' and the 'script' (function in the script editor)? Sorry for the newbie question :-(

Comment: You won't be able to use the simple trigger if you need to write a value.  You'll need to "install" a trigger.  All that means is that you go through a set up process.  Here's a link to something I wrote:  [On Edit Trigger](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15XA-5DQSLNd0ZqgRz7BjaV4c2s-728AR3gPnpdWCEIo/edit)

Comment: Ah, now I understand better - thank you for explaining the installation and putting a condition around it. That doc is now a pdf for me to refer back if I get lost.

Comment: One more question (I don't know if I need to start a new thread). I'm trying to use one sheet for lookup table so I can put conditions in another sheet's cell. I've tried match(), vlookup(), etc. but couldn't make it work. What function or combination do I use (if possible) to do this: in sheet "A" for input it is selection from drop-down list (from sheet 'lookup'!A2:A20). Once it is chosen, say value 'lookup'!A10 for cell A2 on sheet "A", cell B3 on sheet "A" gets the value from 'lookup'!B3? Can this be done through conditions and functions or do I need to script this too? Thank you!

Comment: The first thing you should do, is "take a tour" to learn about how to use Stack Overflow.  At the top of the window, click "help", and then "Tour".  You do need to create a new question.  But first you should search for similar questions.  Of course, the problem is, that when anyone is just starting, you don't know the terminology and it can be impossible to find an answer.  Even when I know there is an answer, and I know the search words to use, I still can't find the post.  This question is very general, so it's technically not a good question.  I don't blame you though.

Comment: Thank you Sandy. I need to acquaint myself with the rules - I will. Thank you again for setting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a workaround by making a menu on the spreadsheet and using the current active cell, the script add the current time on the adjacent row:

Create a spreadsheet and paste this code into the script.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu("Utils")
      .addItem('Generate System Time', 'time')
      .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function time(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var column = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn();

  var date= new Date();

  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var hour = date.getHours();

  ss.getRange(row,column+1).setValue(date);

}
```

You now see a new menu called "Utils". To use it you must be on the cell next to the one you want to add the time, and go to menu Utils, then Generate System Time.

Regards.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response Mario - had an urgent matter to take care of. I am going to try your script tonight and report back (I also want to understand what you did so this is great)!

Comment: Thank you for the script! It works great. I started trying to understand more of the internal working of the script. Since it's driven by menu, I am thinking of formatting the output within the script before showing up in adjacent cell. I'm really excited that there's something new I can learn to add functionality! Thank you again!