# Create and pop up a new email using data from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have spreadsheet in `Google-drive' that contains information like below:
[image]

I need to add a button to each row (suppose that we have more data) and If I click it will pop up an html with a new email that contains info from that spreadsheet and that specific row.

Currently, I've created the following `gs` file in `Apps Script` the following script that creates a draft email. However, I want to create and view the new email in order to add more info to the message and then send it.

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 9);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[7]; // First column
    var message = row[8]; // Second column
    var subject = row[1]+" " + row[6]+ " " + row[1];//'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    GmailApp.createDraft(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39128281/1395874) solution.

I edited my `gs` file in `Apps Script` to have the following script:

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var column = 1;//= sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, column, 10);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var row = data[0];//[i];
  var emailAddress = row[7]; // First column
  var message = row[8]; // Second column
  var subject = row[1]+" " + row[6]+ " " + row[2];//'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';

  GmailApp.createDraft(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu("Send email")
      .addItem('Generate Draft Email', 'sendEmails')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Now, in my menu in my spreadsheet I have `Send Email` tab like below:
[image]

When I go to a selected row, I click the submenu `Generate Draft Email` from `Send Email` and a new email is generated in my Gmail draft emails.